# Hide a property name from output

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api

I have a function that returns data. This data comes from an interface, with a property name. Output has the property name. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

How do I do this?

interface:

```
export interface DataNode {
    id?: number,
    type?: string,
    parentId?: number,
    data?: any,
    children?: DataNode[],
    buildings?: DataNode[],
    areas?: DataNode[],
    rooms?: DataNode[],
    flags?: DataNode[],
    details?: DataNode[]
};
```

Code that creates the output:

```
export const fromCity = async (
    city: entities.City,
    depth: "none" | "immediate" | "full"
): Promise<DataNode> => {
    return {
        id: city.id,
        type: "City",
        data: {
            name: city.name,
            title: city.title,
            // created: city.created,
            // updatedAt: city.updatedAt
        },
        buildings: depth !== "none" ?
            await mapChildren((building: entities.Building): Promise<DataNode> => {
                building.city = building.city || Promise.resolve(city);
                return fromBuilding(
                    building,
                    depth === "immediate" ? "none" : depth
                );
            })(await (city.buildings || Promise.resolve([]))) : []
    };
};
```

Actual output I get from API:

```
            "id": 1,
                "type": "Building",
                "parentId": 1,
                "data": {
                    "name": "data-center",
                    "title": "Data Center",
                    "subtitle": "Secure Data Center and Cloud NOC",
                    "x": "11.30",
                    "y": "41.50"
```

What I do want from the API:

```
            "id": 1,
                "type": "Building",
                "parentId": 1,
                {
                    "name": "data-center",
                    "title": "Data Center",
                    "subtitle": "Secure Data Center and Cloud NOC",
                    "x": "11.30",
                    "y": "41.50"
```

Note the disappearance of `"data":` . That's what I want to hide.

Is there a simple way to tell "don't return this property name, just it's value"?

Answer (score 1):

An object's key must be a string. So the closest you'll get to your desired output would be naming the `"data"` key an empty string `""`

Comment: Although that would work, it breaks another code where I have to reference this same key, and I can't use "" to reference it.

Comment: you could use `object[""]` to reference the empty key

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't let you do that. You can't have a value without a key to access it otherwise that data would be unreachable with an OBJECT. What you can do it make it output this with an Array:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "Building"
    "parentId": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "data-center",
    "title": "Data Center",
    "subtitle": "Secure Data Center and Cloud NOC",
    "x": "11.30",
    "y": "41.50",
  }
]
```

Then you can access data from

```js
JSON.parse(JSONresponse[1]);
```

Comment: I don't need to actually have a non keyed value, I just need to hide it from output. If that's not doable, than I'll have to try other options, like parsing the output as you said.